# Python: How do I ping a range of IP addresses?

Tags: python, networking, cmd, ping

I want to ping a range of IP addresses in Python and print either:
"The IP is reachable with a X% percent package loss" or 
"The IP isn't reachable with a X% package loss"

The range I want to try is 192.168.0.X with X being the range of 0-255

Here is my code so far;

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import os

for x in range(0, 256):
    cmd=shlex.split("ping -cl 192.168.0." + str(x))
    try:
       output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError,e:
       #Will print the command failed with its exit status
       print "The IP {0} isn't reachable".format(cmd[-1])
    else:
       print "The IP {0} is reachable".format(cmd[-1])
```

what is wrong with my code? also I noticed when I try the command "ping -cl 192.168.0.2" it says that -cl is an administrator only command. I am an admin on my computer and I ran cmd as admin so whats wrong with that?

I am using Windows 8.1
Python v2.7.9

Comment: what's your operating system? If you're only in a group called `admin` that's not enough. you have to be `root` to control the packet send rate of ping, because ping can be misused to flood other hosts.

Comment: my os is Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using linux and you just want to see the packet loss:

```
import shlex
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


cmd1 = shlex.split("grep -oP '\d+(?=% packet loss)'")
for x in range(1, 256):
    cmd = "ping  -c 4  192.168.43.{}".format(x).split()
    p1 = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    p2 = Popen(cmd1, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    p1.stdout.close()
    output = p2.communicate()[0].rstrip()
    if output == "100":
        print("{}% percent packet loss from unreachable ip {}".format(output, cmd[-1]))
    else:
        print("{}% percent packet loss from reachable ip {}".format(output, cmd[-1]))
```

Disclaimer I don't use windows so am open to correction but this may work:

```
for x in range(1, 256):
    cmd = "ping  -c 1  192.168.43.{}".format(x).split()
    p1 = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    lines = p1.communicate()[0].splitlines()
    output = (lines[-2]).rsplit(None,5)
    output = output[-5].rstrip()
    if output == "100%":
        print("{} percent packet loss from unreachable ip {}".format(output, cmd[-1]))
    else:
        print("{} percent packet loss from reachable ip {}".format(output, cmd[-1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Definitely helpful, but I am on windows 8.1

Comment: no worries, if you are doing a lot of network related coding python-nmap would be a good way to go. I don't use windows but you should be able to just use the first command and p1 and get the communicate output from that, you can easily split the outputted string to get the data you need

Comment: @NathanielSharp, I added an alternative method without grep. Have a go and see how it works, you will have to change the splitting and ping command to suit the windows output

Answer (score 0):

If you have scapy module installed you should try using :

```
clients = arping("192.168.1.*")
print clients
```

It is fast and will also print the mac adress associated with the ip so it is quite helpful.